# Auto Responder For Mac

Tags: macos, routes, fiddler

All the request to particular domain can be routed to another domain using the fiddler in windows for example, Is it possible in Mac OSX using any way?

The browser send the request to `http://example.com/web/images/image_name.jpg` then the fiddler intercept the request and changed the request to `http://localhost/web/images/image_name.jpg`

see the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

edit file `/etc/hosts` and put in the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

that should do the trick (it will redirect all the traffic to example.com to your localhost)

Comment: I like to do it only for the particular path like http://example.com/web/images to http://localhost/web/images. Is it possible?